# Erro ao instalar o atom-autocomplete-php

Tags: atom

Estou usando o Atom Editor no Linux Mint 18.2 e após instalar o atom-auto-complete-php, dá o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele abre e fecha logo em seguida. Como faço para corrigir esse erro? Gostaria de ressaltar que sou novo no Linux.

Comment: Tem o PHP e o Composer instalado?

Comment: Sim...tenho os dois....Composer version 1.5.1

Comment: Então confira os caminhos especificados nas configurações do editor. Algum deles está errado, possivelmente.

Comment: Muito bom Anderson. Era exatamente isso. O caminho do Composer estava errado, para isso troquei /usr/local/bin/composer para /usr/bin/composer onde está o composer. Obrigado.